# Getting 404 error from CKEditor after image upload to server(NodeJS/express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, ckeditor

I'm having trouble displaying the image I uploaded to the server(built in Node and Express).
I used React for my frontend.
Using React, the image uploads successfully to the server.
But I want the image to display also in the editor, but its not working.
I'm getting a 404 error in the browser. I read somewhere that you have to specify a json response like this:

(this is my code..in the backend):
PS: I'm using multer to read multipart data so that the images can be saved to the server

```
const diskStorage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb)=>{
        // console.log(req.params)
        cb(null, './images')
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb)=>{
        cb(null, Date.now() + file.originalname)
    }
})

const uploads = multer({storage: diskStorage});


app.post('/JournalistPost', uploads.single('upload'), (req, res, next)=>{
    let uploadedFile = req.file.path;
    res.json({
        "uploaded": true,
        "url": uploadedFile
    })
})
```

And this is my frontend(React)

```
 <CKEditor
               editor={ClassicEditor}
               data='<p>Some Text</p>'
               onChange={(event, editor)=>{
                const data = editor.getData();
                setPostData(data)
               }}

               config={ {
                ckfinder: {
                    uploadUrl: '/JournalistPost'
                }
                }
            }
            />
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using path, try destination and it should be the exact url